# Persisting Set<Enum> with Integer value on MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, enums, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Notification` class which contains a `Set<NotificationType>` field notificationType.

When I try to make an insert operation of an instance of `Notification` to `INotificationRepository` that extends `MongoRepository<Notification, String>` notificationType field in Mongo is populated with the constant of enum `NotificationType` (like `["FEED","NOTIFICATION"]`). I expect it to be persisted as `[0,3]`.

How could I persist the value field of the enum to MongoDB?

```
@Document
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Notification {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed
    private Set<NotificationType> notificationType;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum NotificationType {
    FEED(0,"Feed"),
    SMS(1, "Sms"),
    EMAIL(2, "Email"),
    NOTIFICATION(3, "Notification");

    private final Integer value;
    private final String text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually work with MongoDB, but maybe you can use [AttributeConverter](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters)
For example:

```
@Converter
public class NotificationTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Notification, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(NotificationType attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return attribute.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public NotificationType convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
       // convert from Integer to enum
    }
}
```

And add `@Convert` to `notificationType` field:

```
@Convert(converter = NotificationTypeConverter.class)
private Set<NotificationType> notificationType;
```

Comment: Thanks Vinh, I use AttributeConverter implementation successfuly with PostGres , but it didn't work with MongoDB. I set breakpoints to convertToDatabaseColumn method, but it didn't hit.